# Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution). ??????////Problem when install any apt in ubuntu?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04, apt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5nGH.png)The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient21 (= 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3) but 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10 is to be installed
libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10) but 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 is to be installed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you haven't change the repo. When you install a package from a repo, that may install install other package that were already in main repo but of different version. When you remove that repo then the apt don't know how to upgrade.

Another case is when you use multiple package manager (I am preety sure you haven't). So for genune solution you can try

```
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo dpkg --configure -a &&
sudo apt-get autoclean &&
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

if error persist then try removing the packages than caused the conflict and reiinstalling.
As I mentioned before if you should also try to bring back the previous repo you had (if any other wise not necessary)